# CSV file output to Virtual Serial (COM) port to control USB stepper motor

Tags: csv, serial-port, usb, putty, hyperterminal

New to all this. Automation project: camera as input, motors as output. **Using a windows PC is a requirement**. I'm generating a CSV file from the camera (camera python api). Parsing the csv file, I'll move a motor until I reach a minimum value. So far so good.

I have a USB relay controller (http://www.canakit.com/Media/Manuals/UK1104.pdf) to which I want to output a signal from the PC based on the csv. Prefer to use java due to gui reqs. How do I get the csv file to output to a generated virtual serial com port over Java? The tutorial suggests using a terminal emulation program such as PuTTY, hyperterminal, realterm, absolute terminal, etc (all work for manual input), which i've never used (except putty for ssh). Do any of these have a java api? How would all this work? Should I use another language? I'd appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Your question title says "stepper motor" but your actual question is about a relay.  Why the inconsistency?  Oh wow, are you using the relays to control the coils of a stepper motor?  That will be really noisy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has libraries that let you access serial ports on your computer.  One such library is [rxtx](https://github.com/rxtx/rxtx), and there are probably others.  You can use such a library to open the serial port and then send or receive bytes from it.

Terminal programs are intended for interactive use by a human; they not generally meant to be used by another computer program.